# What's the difference between "la compagnie", "l'entreprise" and "la société"?

Tags: vocabulaire, droit-et-justice, économie

Can someone tell me the difference between "la compagnie", "l'entreprise" and "la société"? when it comes to company?

Comment: Most of the French, however, will use all of these the exact same way : "Tu travailles pour quelle compagnie / quelle entreprise / quelle société ?"

Comment: @MonsieurTruite I have never heard a French person saying *tu travailles pour quelle compagnie ?*. That sounds like an anglicism to me. Both other are possible but more common are the casual *Tu travailles chez qui ?* and *tu travailles dans quelle boite ?*.

Answer (score 5):

"La compagnie" is a kind of organisation where several participants are involved ( could be persons or enterprises )
"La société " is an enterprise with a legal ( and controled )existence where some identified persons shares assets and share benefits.
"L'entreprise " is a general term : workers works for a same boss. An Enterprise could be or not a Société.

Answer (score 4):

These words can have many different meanings, but when you talk about "company" as a business entity they are synonyms.

Examples:

"Compagnie d'assurance"

"Société anonyme"

"Entreprise de bâtiment"

Comment: Ils sont synonymes, et pourtant dans ces trois expressions les mots ne sont pas interchangeables.

Answer (score 4):

L'[*entreprise*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8379838) c'est l' « organisation qui, indépendamment de sa forme juridique, exerce une activité marchande afin de répondre aux demandes de clients [...] » (GDT) : c'est l'*entité économique*. Par ailleurs, [au Québec](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299052), on a un usage un peu particulier qui veut qu'en se fondant sur une division dans la tradition de *common law* entre le *partnership* et la *company*, on associe souvent le vocable de *compagnie* à ce qui est en fait une *société par actions*. Dans une vision purement civiliste du vocabulaire, il serait préférable de toutes les voir comme des *sociétés*, soit *de personnes*, soit *de capitaux*, avec leurs sous-catégories respectives, dont la *société par actions* pour la deuxième, tel que l'explique le GDT, et donc de laisser de côté le terme *compagnie* (et éviter l'emploi de *corporation*) dont il faut néanmoins pouvoir reconnaître l'emploi particulier selon le contexte...

Answer (score 2):

A ***compagnie*** provides services and an ***entreprise*** produces goods.

Example : *Compagnie d'assurance* and *Entreprise de travaux publics*.

Answer (score 1):

Définition d'une **société**

> Aux termes de l'article 1832 du [Code civil](https://droit-finances.commentcamarche.com/download/telecharger-198-code-civil-2019-pdf-en-ligne), une société peut se
>   définir comme un acte juridique par lequel deux ou plusieurs personnes
>   conviennent par un contrat d'affecter à une entreprise commune des
>   biens (sommes d'argent, voitures, immeubles) ou leur industrie
>   (compétences...) en vue de partager le bénéfice ou de profiter de
>   l'économie qui pourra en résulter.
>
> La notion de société désigne également la [personne morale](https://droit-finances.commentcamarche.com/faq/4262-personne-morale-definition) créée par le
>   contrat de société. En tant que personne morale, la société dispose
>   d'un patrimoine composé à l'origine des biens apportés par les
>   associés ou les actionnaires. La personnalité morale d'une société est
>   acquise lors de l'immatriculation de celle-ci au RCS ([Registre du commerce et des sociétés](https://droit-finances.commentcamarche.com/faq/23971-registre-du-commerce-definition)).

Définition d'une **entreprise**

> Contrairement à la société, l'entreprise ne fait pas l'objet d'une
>   réelle définition légale. C'est une notion avant tout économique et
>   sociale. En matière économique, elle peut se définir comme une unité
>   organisée reposant sur la mise en œuvre de moyens humains et
>   matériels de production ou de distribution. Dans les textes de loi, on
>   retrouve de façon récurrente la notion d'entreprise dans le [Code du
>   travail](https://droit-finances.commentcamarche.com/download/telecharger-204-code-du-travail-2019-pdf-en-ligne), au sein duquel le terme doit être interprété comme un
>   ensemble de travailleurs exerçant une activité commune sous l'autorité
>   d'un même employeur.

Les **compagnies** n'existent pas en france, du moins au plan juridique, même si elles en portent le nom. En revanche elles exitent au Québec toujours sur le plan Juridique.

Source: [Droit-finances](https://droit-finances.commentcamarche.com/faq/20637-difference-entre-entreprise-et-societe-definitions)

Answer (score 0):

Are airlines not typically referred to as ´les compagnies aérienne’?  I thought so.  I think of ‘entreprise’ as more of an entrepreneurial business, perhaps with independent contractors, but it also applies to big outfits as a more generic all encompassing term for an organized offering of services.  Une société has a corporate ring to it, and the SA after a business name in France is an abbreviation of ‘societe anonyme,’ which is equivalent to Inc. in the US (incorporated).